# Decode JSON to PHP

Tags: php, json, decode

I have a .txt file called 'test.txt' that is a JSON array like this:

```
  [{"email":"chrono@gmail.com","createdate":"2016-03-23","source":"email"}]
```

I'm trying to use PHP to decode this JSON array so I can send my information over to my e-mail database for capture. I've created a PHP file with this code:

```
 <?php 

 $url = 'http://www.test.com/sweeps/test.txt';
 $content = file_get_contents($url);
 $json = json_decode($content,true);

 echo $json; 


 ?>
```

For some reason, it's not echoing the decoded JSON when I visit my php page. Is there a reason for this and can anyone shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: It's not JSON after decode, its a PHP array: `print_r($json);` and/or loop over it and echo the elements.

Comment: `$foo = array('a','b'); echo $foo` outputs the literal word `Array`, not the contents of the array. you cannot echo/print arrays directly.

Comment: This json string is missing a quote in the "email" field. Fix that, and it decodes just fine.

Comment: It seems like the Json is missing an extra quote that can be causing the error. *(before the email field)*

Comment: Apologies, I actually handwrote the JSON because it's three entries. The full version is here: http://pastebin.ca/3409494

Comment: For some reason, var_dump gives me a NULL and print_r doesn't show anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

You use `echo` to print scalar variables like

```
$x = 'Fred';
echo $x;
```

To print an array or object you use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
print_r($array);
```

As `json_decode()` takes a JSON string and converts it to a PHP array or object use `print_r()` for example.

Also if the `json_decode()` fails for any reason there is a function provided to print the error message.

```
<?php 
 $url = 'http://www.test.com/sweeps/test.txt';
 $content = file_get_contents($url);
 $json = json_decode($content,true);

 if ( json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE ) {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
    exit;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Any reason why var_dump will show a NULL and print_r won't show anything? My actual JSON entries from woobox is here: http://pastebin.ca/3409494

Comment: If you run that JSON String through [the json lint validator](http://jsonlint.com) you will see that it is not valid JSON. Or use the `json_last_error()` code I added to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to split that json string into two separate json strings (judging by the pastebin you've provided). Look for "][", break there, and try with any of the parts you end up with:

```
$tmp = explode('][', $json_string);

if (!count($tmp)) {
    $json = json_decode($json_string);

    var_dump($json);
} else {
    foreach ($tmp as $json_part) {
        $json = json_decode('['.rtrim(ltrim($json_string, '['), ']').']');

        var_dump($json);
    }
}
```