# How to decode JSON to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON output I would like to convert to a PHP array.
I tried with json_decode(), the problem is that there are arrays in the arrays.
They are the first weapons with PHP and I have never used JSON.
Can anyone help me?

Here is the JSON code:

```
{
    "a": "text",
    "b": "",

    "c": [

        {"name": "1", "id": "some text 1", "val": "x"},
        {"name": "2", "id": "some text 2", "val": "x"},
        {"name": "3", "id": "some text 3", "val": "x"}

    ]

}
```

I have to check that a variable is equal to name 1, contained in c, and if so, it also takes its id and val.

How can I do?

*PS: I can compare two variables, but I do not know how to find name 1 and the corresponding data ..*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode JSON to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184680/decode-json-to-php)

Comment: It's OK, you just decode it once, and all will be an array inside array too

Comment: How is the array c defined?

Comment: Loop through the c array and test the value of name. How is this complicated?

Comment: Sorry, I never worked with a array inside an array, now understood.
Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = '{"a":"text","b":"","c":[{"name":"1","id":"some text 1","val":"x"},{"name":"2","id":"some text 2","val":"x"},{"name":"3","id":"some text 3","val":"x"}]}';

$json = json_decode($json,true);

echo $json["a"]."<br>";
echo $json["b"]."<br>";
echo $json["c"][1]["name"]."<br>";
echo "<pre>".print_r($json,true)."</pre>";
```